# iOS App only ranges beacons when device connected to debugger

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

We're successfully ranging beacons (estimotes in this case but not with their SDK) and I can range beacons all day when my device is plugged into the computer and running through Xcode. But when I archive my build and deploy it to our testers (and even on the same device, but through the archive build) no beacons are ranging.

Not much point showing code here since it works fine in the debugger. Any ideas? Is it a capabilities issue? We've turned on Location Updates (which Apple said wasn't needed for beacons, but I don't know), Bluetooth LE, Background fetch and Remote Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain this observation.  I have apps that successfully do ranging both with the debugger connected and with an archived build.  You do not need any special background modes.

I would add NSLog statements when you start ranging and get callbacks, then install the archived IPA and look for the logging statements in XCode Devices, and see if you can figure out what is going on.